# How to clear HTML5 canvas after scale

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a problem while i work with canvas. See below code.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>    
<input id="but" type="button" value="clear canvas" onclick="ClearCanvas()">
```

**JS**

```
can = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = can.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(205,190,245)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

ctx.scale(0.4, 0.4);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(105,180,235)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

$("#but").click(function()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

    ctx.scale(1, 1);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
});
```

While i click on "clear canvas" button, it is not clearing entire canvas. It is just clearing the portion that was scaled. How to clear whole canvas after did scaling?

You can catch this live in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/uGnhx/)

**Note: No problem in FF.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
ctx.scale(1, 1);
```

Should read:

```
ctx.scale(2.5, 2.5);
```

Initially you reduced the scale from 1 to 0.4 which is 2.5 times smaller than the original scale.  (1 / 0.4 = 2.5)

Setting a scale to 1 will scale by 100% i.e no change.

Other options are:

- Replace ctx.scale(1, 1); with ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
- Use Save() and Restore() [link](http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/)

Comment: is there any document for that? are you sure it is proper way of doing this?

Comment: Another way would be to use Save() and Restore() [link](http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/)

Comment: Or you could replace the ctx.scale(1, 1) with        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

Comment: cool. can you update all these options to above answer. i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i use for clear the canvas even if you have a scale

```html
let scale_factor = 1+this.zoom
this.scaleCumulate *= scale_factor
ctx.scale(scale_factor,scale_factor)

...

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width / this.scaleCumulate, this.canvas.height / this.scaleCumulate)
```